# Trying to submit this Angular 7 form onto my typescript. ngForm and [(ngModel)]

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, forms, typescript

I am trying to get this simple form information to be passed using the onSubmit() function but when executing it it complains of being undefined on start. Am I messing some of the syntax up?

```
<form class="gf-formbox" name="credentials" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gf-email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="gf-email" placeholder="Enter email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gf-pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="gf-pass" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.pristine">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is undefined. Provide us the full error stack and the related typescript portion of your component.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to declare the variables in your component then access the inputs on submitting the form. Here is a demo of how you can achieve that.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwumm4enter code here

On your component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private email: string;
  private password: string;

  onSubmit(f){
    console.log(this.email);
    console.log(this.password)
  }
}
```

On your template:

```html
<form class="gf-formbox" name="credentials" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gf-email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="gf-email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="gf-pass">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="gf-pass" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.pristine">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get form information Angular has two types of form approach -

- Template-driven forms [Guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms), [stackblitz example1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodel-form-2496kc)
- Reactive Forms [Guide](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), [stackblitz example2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-reactive-form-validation-gfnyzz?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

You can choose any of them as per your requirement. Hope it will help :)